# Как защитить сайт от атак?

Tags: php, сессия

В моем сайте PHPSESSID хранится в Cookie. И с клиентской стороны это видно. Как можно скрыть PHPSESSID, чтобы не было возможности на xss атак.

Comment: не использовать сессии, иначе он так или иначе будет передаваться клиенту. И если честно, не совсем понял при чем здесь xss и PHPSESSID? Рекомендую почитать статьи от [The Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page), там и про xss много написано

Comment: В  сайте есть данные которые хранятся в куках, я не могу без куки работать. А что касается про xss , то всявь PHPSESSID будет доступны данные юзер это я тестировала и xss присуствует.

Comment: ну так надо бороться с xss, а не с последствиями, посмотрите тот сайт, там много интересного, в том числе примеры того как надо бороться (например, [это](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), или [это](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), или [это](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) и т.д.). Общая идея - никогда не доверяйте данным, полученным от пользователя, корректно обрабатывая такие данные можно избавить себя от многих проблем

Comment: Эти сайты не знакомы, просто хотелось бы найти русское документация :) . Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 4):

Самое главное - не путаться.

> В моем сайте PHPSESSID хранится в Cookie.

Это нормально.

> И с клиентской стороны это видно.

Это тоже нормально.

> Как можно скрыть PHPSESSID

Это делать не нужно.

> чтобы не было возможности на xss атак.

PHPSESSID не имеет отношения к xss. И к sql инъекциям - тоже

С XSS надо бороться, экранируя все выводимые данные по умолчанию. Для этого надо использовать хороший шаблонизатор, например Twig.

Comment: Ещё можно изменить название сессионной куки с "PHPSESSID" на что-то другое, напр., "HACKHERE" – см. параметр [`session.name`](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) в php.ini – может, это добавит уверенности автору вопроса )

Comment: О xss атак я прочитала вот тут.  http://lifeexample.ru/razrabotka-i-optimizacia-saita/xss-uyazvimost-i-zashhita-ot-xss.html

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan хотя там автор и пишет ерунду про защиту, но про суть атаки пишет верно. У него ничего нет про то что надо скрывать куки.

Comment: @Ипатьев да знаю, что там про это нечего не написано, я так думаю что можно было бы скрыть PHPSESSID.

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan нет, нельзя. Если сессию скрыть, то она не будет работать. Почитайте про сессии, http://phpfaq.ru/sessions